# cannot install 16.04 - missing dependency

Tags: 16.04, dependencies

Ubuntu tells me there is an upgrade when I boot and starts the install process but then I get an error message -  The required dependency 'apt(>=1.0.1ubuntu2.13)' is not installed. How can Install or recover this and continue with the upgrade please? Thanks. Matt.

Comment: What are you currently running?  And have you installed all updates of the current version?

Comment: As suggested all updates installed (took around 30 minutes) and the upgrade is now running as expected - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change your update mirror to the main mirror first, then do an update. Once you have updated, reboot and run the upgrade. 
I had the same issue.
That is as short as I can make it.